# How to get last column letter of gsheet or excel using their fomula

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I am struggling to get last column letter of gsheet or excel using their formula. I have a sheet that I will add new column every time I work on it, and need the last column letter to put it on other my formula.

I want to  use it on formula like sum like

```
=sum(j4:lastcolumn)
```

Comment: `=LEFT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMNS(1:1),4),LEN(ADDRESS(1,COLUMNS(1:1),4))-1)` This one?

Comment: @ENIAC, thank you, but can i use it on formula like sum? like 
=sum(j4:LEFT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMNS(1:1),4),LEN(ADDRESS(1,COLUMNS(1:1),4))-1))

Comment: You asked about last column **letter**. How do you want to sum column letter and cell value?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a contiguous range, You'd use `INDEX/COUNTA`:

- `COUNTA` to get number of columns
- `INDEX` to get the range

You can then use it in a formula like this:

```
=SUM(A4:INDEX(4:4,COUNTA(4:4)))
```

If last column is `K`, This equals `SUM(A4:K4)`

Comment: Would that work with empty columns in between ? But I vote up anyways since this is a complete answer to the question.

Comment: @Marios No. Therefore my  condition on the very first line of answer: "contiguous range". However if the blanks are constant(say, 2 blanks always), you could simply add to count: `=SUM(A4:INDEX(4:4,COUNTA(4:4)+2))`

Answer (score 2):

### Solution:

You can create your own [custom formula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) to achieve this task using Google Apps Script. The following script will get the last column with content using the [getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn) method and then a regular expression to map the index of the last column with the respective column letter.

```
function findLastColumn() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  const lastC = sh.getLastColumn();
  var range = sh.getRange(1, lastC, 1, 1);
  return range.getA1Notation().match(/([A-Z]+)/)[0];
}
```

The aforementioned code snippet will give you the letter of the last column with content.

If you want to maximum column in your sheet, then replace:

```
sh.getLastColumn();
```

with

```
sh.getMaxColumns();
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for the letter. No need for VBA

To create the range to sum:

- First get the column number of the last column in a row that contains a number (doesn't matter if there are empty columns in between):

  ```
    =LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(4:4),COLUMN(4:4))
  ```
- Then Combine it with the INDEX function to obtain the relevant range:

  ```
    =J4:INDEX(4:4,1,LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(4:4),COLUMN(4:4)))
  ```

So your end formula would be:

```
=SUM(J4:INDEX(4:4,1,LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(4:4),COLUMN(4:4))))
```

Of course, at least for this simple formula, the same result would obtain with:

```
=sum(j4:xfd4)
```